# Create working contact form within basket

Tags: php

I've taken over a website where the developer created a bespoke wishlist/basket. Technically it was working but it wasn't getting much response from anyone. I've been tasked with adding a contact form to the end of the process that emails the details to the company. I've used the same contact form on various sites but can't get it to work on this one.

Here's the problematic bit of code:

```
<script>
function quoteme() {
        $("#msgbox_body").html('<div id="contactform"><form class="form" method="POST" action="http://www.dtrmedical.com"><table border="0"><tbody><tr><td><p class="name"><label for="name">Your Name:</label></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td></tr><tr><td><p class="email"><label for="email">E-mail:</label></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td></tr><tr><td><p class="tel"><label for="tel">Telephone:</label></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" /></td></tr><tr><td><p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table><? if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { $to = "rob@teamworksdesign.com"; $subject = "DTR Medical Contact enquiry"; $name_field = $_POST['name']; $email_field = $_POST['email']; $tel_field = $_POST['tel']; $body = "DTR Medical,\n\n You have an enquiry from the website, please see the details below:\n\n Name: $name_field\n Company Name: $companyname_field\n Address: $address_field, $address1_field, $address2_field\n Town: $town_field\n County: $county_field\n Postcode: $postcode_field\n Country: $country_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Tel: $tel_field\n Message:\n $enquiry_field"; mail($to, $subject, $body); echo "Thank you for getting in touch, we will contact you shortly.";} ?></form></div>');
        $("#msgbox_actions").html('<input onclick="jQuery.facebox({ ajax: \'wishlist.php?emailme=true\' })" type="button" value="Save list for later" /> <input onclick="jQuery.facebox({ ajax: \'wishlist.php?basket=true\' })" type="button" value="Back to Wishlist" />');
}
</script>
```

The problem is the form just goes to a blank page on submission. Also I'd like to what products the customer wants in the email that gets sent to the company.

Here's all the code in it's entirety:

```
<? include "db.php";

function createcode($length = 8, $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890')
{
    $chars_length = (strlen($chars) - 1);
    $string = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
    for ($i = 1; $i < $length; $i = strlen($string))
    {
        $r = $chars{rand(0, $chars_length)};
        if ($r != $string{$i - 1}) $string .=  $r;
    }
    return $string;
}

if (!$_SESSION[cartid] AND ($_POST[update_product] OR $_GET[loadcode])) {
    //echo "<script>alert('cart setup!')</script>";
    getmycartcode();
}

function getmycartcode() {

    $mycart = mysql_query("SELECT id,basketcode FROM wishlistsaved WHERE sesid = '$sesid'");
    $cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($mycart);

    $sesid = session_id();

    if (!$cart[id]) {
        while ($usecode == false) {
            $basketcode = createcode();
            $findcode = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM wishlistsaved WHERE basketcode = '$sesid'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($findcode) == 0) { $usecode = true; }
        }
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO wishlistsaved (sesid, expires, basketcode) VALUES ('$sesid', NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY, '$basketcode')");
        $_SESSION[cartid] = $basketcode;
    } else {
        $_SESSION[cartid] = $cart[basketcode];
    }


    //delete old wishlists!
    $deletethese = mysql_query("SELECT sesid,id FROM wishlistsaved WHERE expires <= NOW()");
    while ($delete = mysql_fetch_assoc($deletethese)) {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$delete[sesid]'");
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM wishlistsaved WHERE id = '$delete[id]'");
    }
}

if ($_POST[updatebasket]) {

    $mybasket = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$sesid' ORDER BY pid,qid,oid ASC");
    while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($mybasket)) {
        $postname = $item[pid]."_".$item[qid]."_".$item[oid];
        $thisqty = $_POST[$postname];
        if ($thisqty) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE wishlistbasket SET qty = '$thisqty' WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND id = '$item[id]'")or die(mysql_error());
        } else {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM wishlistbasket WHERE id = '$item[id]' AND sesid = '$sesid'")or die(mysql_error());
        }

    }
    header("Location: index.php?id=3&basket=true");
    exit;
}

if ($_GET[clearall]) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$sesid'");
}

if ($_POST[update_product]) {

    $productid = $_POST[productid];
    $get_product_quantities = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_quantities WHERE product_id='$productid' ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($product_quantity = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_product_quantities)) {

        $get_product_options = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_options WHERE quantity_id='$product_quantity[id]' ORDER BY id ASC");
        while ($product_option = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_product_options)) {
            $postname = $productid."_".$product_quantity[id]."_".$product_option[id];
            $thisqty = $_POST[$postname];
                $item = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND pid = '$productid' AND qid = '$product_quantity[id]' AND oid = '$product_option[id]'");
                    if (mysql_num_rows($item) == 0) {
                        $noitem = true;
                        echo "no item<br />";
                    } else {
                        $noitem = false;
                        echo "item found<br />";
                    }
                if ($thisqty) {
                    if ($noitem) { //doesnt exist yet so add it to basket
                        echo "insert<br />";
                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO wishlistbasket (sesid, pid, qid, oid, qty) VALUES ('$sesid','$productid','$product_quantity[id]','$product_option[id]','$thisqty')")or die(mysql_error());
                    } else { //already exists so update basket!
                        echo "update<br />";
                        mysql_query("UPDATE wishlistbasket SET qty = '$thisqty' WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND pid = '$productid' AND qid = '$product_quantity[id]' AND oid = '$product_option[id]'")or die(mysql_error());
                    }
                } else { //no post item found but found in basket so delete from basket!
                    echo "delete<br />";
                    if (!$noitem) { mysql_query("DELETE FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND pid = '$productid' AND qid = '$product_quantity[id]' AND oid = '$product_option[id]'")or die(mysql_error()); }
                }
        }
    }

    header("Location: index.php?id=3&productid=$productid");
    exit;
}

if ($_GET[loadcode]) {
    $mycode = $_GET[loadcode];

    if ($mycode == $_SESSION[cartid]) {
          echo "<br />The code you entered is the same as the code already loaded.<br /><input type=\"text\" name=\"loadcode\" id=\"loadcode\" value=\"$mycode\" class=\"loadcode\" />";
          exit;
    }

    $mycart = mysql_query("SELECT sesid,id FROM wishlistsaved WHERE basketcode = '$mycode'");
    $cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($mycart);

    if (mysql_num_rows($mycart) == 0) { //did not find code!
        echo "<br />Sorry the code you entered wasn't found, please check the code and try again...<br /><input type=\"text\" name=\"loadcode\" id=\"loadcode\" value=\"$mycode\" class=\"loadcode\" />";
    } else { //found code and do stuff!
        echo "<br />Code successful, your wish list has been loaded and the code '$mycode'<br />is valid for another 14 days to use again.<br />";
        $getitems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$cart[sesid]'");
        while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($getitems)) {
            $searchitems = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND pid = '$item[pid]' AND qid = '$item[qid]' AND oid = '$item[oid]'")or die(mysql_error());
            if (mysql_num_rows($searchitems) == 1) {
                $searched = mysql_fetch_assoc($searchitems);
                $newqty = $searched[qty] + $item[qty];
                mysql_query("UPDATE wishlistbasket SET qty = '$newqty' WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND pid = '$item[pid]' AND qid = '$item[qid]' AND oid = '$item[oid]'")or die(mysql_error());
            } else {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO wishlistbasket (sesid, pid, qid, oid, qty) VALUES ('$sesid','$item[pid]','$item[qid]','$item[oid]','$item[qty]')")or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
        mysql_query("UPDATE wishlistsaved SET expires = NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY WHERE id = '$cart[id]'");
    }
    exit;

}

if ($_GET[myemail]) {

    $message = "<font face=Tahoma size=2>Your wish list code is: $_SESSION[cartid]<br /><br />For an updated view of whats in your wish list please type your code into our website: http://www.dtrmedical.com/products/ <br /><br />Many Thanks,<br />DTR Medical</font>";
    $headers = "From: noreply@dtrmedical.com\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
           "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
           "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
           "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";

    mail($_GET[myemail],'Your DTRMedical Wishlist Code',$message,$headers);

    echo "<br />Your code has been sent to: <b>$_GET[myemail]</b>";

    exit;
}

if ($_GET[newcode]) {

if ($_SESSION[cartid]) {
    $mycart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistsaved WHERE sesid = '$sesid'");
    $cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($mycart);

    if ($cart[id]) { $currentcart = "<br />
    Your current wish list code is: <strong>$cart[basketcode]</strong>, insert your new code below:
    <br />"; }

}

?>
<div id="msgbox_title">Load Wish List...<div id="closeme" onclick="jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox')">x</div></div>
<form method="post">
<div id="msgbox_body">Here you can load a previous wish list by using the code that was provided to you,<br />remember these codes expire 14 days after being created.
<br />
<div id="newcode">
<? echo $currentcart; ?>
<input type="text" name="loadcode" id="loadcode" class="loadcode" />
</div></div>
<div id="msgbox_actions"><input type="button" onclick="loadmycode()" value="Load Code" /></div>
</form>
<script>
function loadmycode() {
        var thiscode = $("#loadcode").val();
        $("#newcode").html('<br />loading code...<br />');
            $('#newcode').load('wishlist.php?loadcode='+thiscode, "",
                function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    if(textStatus == 'error') {
                        var msg = "Error:<br />";
                        $("#newcode").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                }
            );
}
</script>
<? } else if ($_GET[addproduct]) { 

$productid = $_GET[addproduct];
$get_product_quantities = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_quantities WHERE product_id='$productid' ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

?>
<form method="post" action="wishlist.php">
<input type="hidden" name="update_product" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" name="productid" value="<? print $productid; ?>" />
<div id="msgbox_title">Choose your option quantities...<div id="closeme" onclick="jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox')">x</div></div>
<div id="msgbox_body">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" align="center">
<?php
    while ($product_quantity = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_product_quantities)) {
?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="padding:0px 9px">
            <strong><?php echo $product_quantity['quantity_name']; ?>:</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $get_product_options = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_options WHERE quantity_id='$product_quantity[id]' ORDER BY id ASC");
    if (mysql_num_rows($get_product_options)==0) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>No products in this quantity</td></tr>";
    } else {
?>
        <tr>
        <td style="width: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 50px;"><span style="color: #aaa;">QTY:</span></td>
        <td style="width: 60px;"><span style="color: #aaa;">Code:</span></td>
        <td style="width: 380px;"><span style="color: #aaa;">Description:</span></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    while ($product_option = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_product_options)) {
    $thisitem = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$sesid' AND pid = '$productid' AND qid = '$product_quantity[id]' AND oid = '$product_option[id]'");
  $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($thisitem);
?>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td><input type="textbox" class="textbox" value="<? echo $item[qty]; ?>" name="<? echo $productid."_".$product_quantity[id]."_".$product_option[id]; ?>" /></td>
        <td style="color: #7c7c7c;font-size:11px;"><?php echo $product_option['product_code']; ?>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $product_option['description']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<?php
    } // END while ($product_option = mysql_fetch_assoc( ...

    } // END if (mysql_num_rows($get_product_options)==0) ... else
?>
    <tr colspan="4"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<?php
    } // END while ($product_quantity = mysql_fetch_assoc ...
?>
</table>

</div>
<div id="msgbox_actions"><input type="submit" value="Add To Wish List" /></div>
</form>
<? } else if ($_GET[basket]) { ?>
<div id="msgbox_title">Your Wish List<div id="closeme" onclick="jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox')">x</div></div>
<form method="post" action="wishlist.php">
<div id="msgbox_body" style="max-height:400px;min-height:100px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;">
<input type="hidden" name="updatebasket" value="1" />
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" align="center" style="min-width:390px;">
<?

    $mycart = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistsaved WHERE sesid = '$sesid'");
    $cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($mycart);

    $mybasket = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wishlistbasket WHERE sesid = '$sesid' ORDER BY pid,qid,oid ASC");
    if (mysql_num_rows($mybasket) == 0) { echo "<tr><td><br /><br /><center>There are no items in your wish list.</center></td></tr>"; $listempty = true; }
    while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($mybasket)) {

        if ($thispid <> $item[pid]) {
            $products = mysql_query("SELECT product_name FROM products WHERE id = '$item[pid]'");
            $product = mysql_fetch_assoc($products);

            if ($thispid <> "") { $br = "<br />"; }

            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\" style=\"text-align: right;\">$br<strong style=\"font-size:14px;\">$product[product_name]</strong></td></tr>";
            $thispid = $item[pid];
        }

        if ($thisqid <> $item[qid]) {
            $quanities = mysql_query("SELECT quantity_name FROM product_quantities WHERE id = '$item[qid]'");
            $thisqty = mysql_fetch_assoc($quanities);

            echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\"><strong style=\"display:block;padding-top:5px;\">$thisqty[quantity_name]</strong></td></tr>";
            $thisqid = $item[qid];
        }

        $get_product_options = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_options WHERE id = '$item[oid]' ORDER BY id ASC");
        $product_option = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_product_options);

        ?>
      <tr>
          <td> </td>
          <td style="padding:0px 2px;"><input type="textbox" class="textbox" value="<? echo $item[qty]; ?>" name="<? echo $item[pid]."_".$item[qid]."_".$item[oid]; ?>" /></td>
          <td style="padding:0px 8px;color: #7c7c7c;font-size:11px;"><?php echo $product_option['product_code']; ?></td>
          <td style="padding:0px 2px;font-size:11px;"><?php echo $product_option['description']; ?></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
        <?

    }

?>
</table>
</div>
<script>
function quoteme() {
        $("#msgbox_body").html('<div id="contactform"><form class="form" method="POST" action="http://www.dtrmedical.com"><table border="0"><tbody><tr><td><p class="name"><label for="name">Your Name:</label></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td></tr><tr><td><p class="email"><label for="email">E-mail:</label></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td></tr><tr><td><p class="tel"><label for="tel">Telephone:</label></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="text" name="tel" id="tel" /></td></tr><tr><td><p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></p></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table><? if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { $to = "rob@teamworksdesign.com"; $subject = "DTR Medical Contact enquiry"; $name_field = $_POST['name']; $email_field = $_POST['email']; $tel_field = $_POST['tel']; $body = "DTR Medical,\n\n You have an enquiry from the website, please see the details below:\n\n Name: $name_field\n Company Name: $companyname_field\n Address: $address_field, $address1_field, $address2_field\n Town: $town_field\n County: $county_field\n Postcode: $postcode_field\n Country: $country_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Tel: $tel_field\n Message:\n $enquiry_field"; mail($to, $subject, $body); echo "Thank you for getting in touch, we will contact you shortly.";} ?></form></div>');
        $("#msgbox_actions").html('<input onclick="jQuery.facebox({ ajax: \'wishlist.php?emailme=true\' })" type="button" value="Save list for later" /> <input onclick="jQuery.facebox({ ajax: \'wishlist.php?basket=true\' })" type="button" value="Back to Wishlist" />');
}
</script>
<? if (!$listempty) { ?>
<div id="msgbox_actions"><input onclick="quoteme()" type="button" value="Request quote" /> <!-- <input onclick="jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'wishlist.php?emailme=true' })" type="button" value="Save list for later" /> --> <input type="submit" value="Update Qty's" /> <input onclick="jQuery.facebox({ ajax: 'wishlist.php?basket=true&clearall=true' })" type="button" value="Clear list" /></div>
<? } ?>
</form>
</div>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the form goes to a blank page is because the `<form>` has the `action` attribute set to `whishlist.php` AND on submit you are not stopping the `form's` submit action which is to navigate to the given page with the supplied parameters using the method (post or get) you provided.

To avoid redirection add `return false;` at the end of `onclick` function of the submit button.

Aside from that you have many things wrong with your code. Before I try to fix them, I would need to know what is the end result you want.

Do you want the `whishlist.php` to send the mail ?

What is the code in `whishlist.php` as that is the page requested via ajax and thus will be responsible for initiating any server side action.

Also why are you using PHP `<? ?>` code in your javascript function `quoteme()` as the `$.html()` contents. It wont work that way.

*The most likely solution to your problem is (best guess without the additional info):*

Add the email sending code to `wishlist.php`, AND send the `name`, `email` and `telephone` to wishlist.php via `AJAX` which you are already doing with only one parameter.

So your wishlist.php should look like :

```
...
if(isset($_GET['emailme']) && $_GET['emailme'] == 'true') { 
    $to = "youremail@company.com"; 
    $subject = "Company Contact enquiry"; 
    $name_field = $_GET['name']; 
    $email_field = $_GET['email']; 
    $tel_field = $_GET['tel']; 

    /* get other needed details */

    $body = "Company,\n\n You have an enquiry from the website, please see the details below:\n\n Name: $name_field\n Company Name: $companyname_field\n Address: $address_field, $address1_field, $address2_field\n Town: $town_field\n County: $county_field\n Postcode: $postcode_field\n Country: $country_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Tel: $tel_field\n Message:\n $enquiry_field"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $body); 
    echo "Thank you for getting in touch, we will contact you shortly.";
}
....
```

While your `AJAX` Call on submit button should be like:

```
jQuery.facebox({ ajax: (\'wishlist.php?emailme=true&name=\' + this.form.name.value + \'&email=\' + this.form.email.value + \'&tel=\' + this.form.tel.value) }); return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, only just getting back to this. Yes I want wishlist.php to send the email with my contact form code. Using PHP in Javascript - didn't know this at the time. I'll give your code a go shortly and let you know the results.

Comment: I've tried putting your form code above within $("#msgbox_body").html(''); and when trying to open the wishlist on the site it just loads a blank box. I also tried putting the submit button in but wasn't able to see that as it wouldn't load. Also would it be possible to put the items that were added to the wishlist into the email that gets sent?

Comment: @Rob I see that you have updated the site and the form for e-mail is no longer there. So To answer your questions. The previous setup you had That I checked 2 Days back was working fine except for the `wishlist.php` and AJAX call. So there the Submit button on the e-mail form would make the AJAX call and as for sending the list of items in wishlist, you can use the SESSION object (where you are storing it in the first place) to get and send it in email. Which can be used to retrieve the wishlist on `wishlist.php` and add the items to email.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll re-try. I'm on and off the project at the moment (hence the reverting back to old code on the site). Really appreciate your help, I'll get back to you with the results.

Comment: @Rob as for where the AJAX code goes it should go in your `quoteme()` function, as the code to be executed on form submit.

Comment: Ok great, thanks. Bear with me while I get through a few other things and I'll get back to this.

Comment: Hi, I'm back onto this now. Just tried out the code and it doesn't seem to do anything on submit. The form comes through to me so it's ok to give it a go. http://www.dtrmedical.com

Comment: @Rob I have tested the form and the AJAX request is actually being made. Do you have the code in `wishlist.php` in place ? As i checked via Chrome's Dev tools that an AJAX request is actually being made with all the correct parameters set.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3838/discussion-between-rob-and-danishgoel)

Comment: Hi again, any chance you'll be able to help on some related things today? We're doing some major changes (removing quantities and replacing with tick boxes) and it's a bit over my head!

Comment: @Rob Well my hands are pretty full right now (I'm doing a major rewrite of one of my websites, which may take a day or two). But if you have a specific query you can ask a question here and provide the link to that question in a comment here so I'll see it when I get some time.

Comment: Hi there. Is there any chance you could take a look at my follow up question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658399/adding-multiple-products-to-a-custom-basket. Although it's not eligible just yet I'll add a bounty to it.

Comment: @Rob I'll look at it in a moment. My website rewrite is complete, but looks like I have been burdened with more work yet again. But I'll try me best to help you with it as soon as I get some time on my hand.

Comment: Apologies for all the chopping and changing but this is the final question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677019/pass-tick-boxes-through-basket-process