# Pass tick boxes through basket process

Tags: php, html, shopping-cart, cart

I'm working on a custom basket - http://www.dtrmedical.com/test-site/index.php?id=3&productid=130. I want to pass the checkbox options chosen from one form to the other.

I have two forms that represent two stages of a basket:

1. To see the first form click the "add to wish list button". Check some options then click the "add to wish list" button at the bottom.
2. To see the second form, click the green "wish list button". This will show the options that were chosen.

**I want to show the options that were ticked in the first form, ticked on the second form. How could I do this?**

Should you wish to see the code in it's entirety - http://pastebin.com/W3UVSSEx

The first form starts on line 197 and the second on line 276.

The checkboxes in both forms are displayed in this manner:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       name="<? echo $productid."_".$product_quantity[id]."_".$product_option[id]; ?>" 
       value="<? echo $quote[qty]; ?>" 
/>

<input type="checkbox" 
       name="<? echo $productid."_".$product_quantity[id]."_".$product_option[id]; ?>" 
       value="<? echo $sample[qty]; ?>" 
/>
```

I've attempted to use `isset` but I'm not sure what to check against as my checkbox names are variables.

Comment: The information you've given in your question is not sufficient to answer your question. Next to that your question does not fit for the format here on SO. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). As you told, the question is not about code that you've been written but you have problem to deal with code of somebody else. Ask that somebody else to explain you the code and discuss the problem with her/him instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your second form, build your checkbox the same way has you build on the first, and when you write the HTML from the loop andd checked="checked" to every checkbox who return that they are set exemple :

This is how the name of the checkbox are defined

`$item[pid]."_".$item[qid]."_".$item[oid]`

so in the loop that generate that just check like this

```
if (isset($_post[$item[pid]."_".$item[qid]."_".$item[oid]])) { 
 //Build your checkbox HTML with the checked="checked";
} else { 
 // Build your normal checkbox (unticked)
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, upon opening up the second popup (the wishlist) everything remained unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do on the second form is access the POST variables via:

`isset($_post['My_Checkbox_Name'])`

and re-set the checkboxes as appropriate on the second page.

Comment: Also baring in my that the checkbox names are variables.